# Are there differences between a Fact Constellation Schema and a Galaxy Schema?

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I am currently working on the two schemes and I'm just not sure if they are the same or if there are differences. In the literature both are often synonymous. Now I've read that there are differences (but I hardly find that on the internet).

Is it true that the difference to the Constellation schema is that the fact table does not have to be hierarchical or otherwise directly connected? - but can be very well (instead of the galaxy schema)?